# How to select specific objects on SQL excluding some by name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this database scheme

```
professor(profname, deptname)
department(deptname, building)
committee(commname, profname)
```

Now, I want to select all Professors who are in Committees where professor 'Piper' is not, I tried this code:

```
select *
from Committee
where NOT profname='Piper';
```

But this actually returns all committees and professor names, except the tuples with the name of 'Piper'.

P.s. I'm using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a distinct list of professors on committees that Piper is not on.  This would be something like this:

```
select distinct c.profname
from committee c
where not exists (select 1
                  from committeee c2
                  where c2.commname = c.commname and c2.profname = 'Piper'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Some set approach:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.profname
FROM committee c
LEFT JOIN committee piperComittee
  ON c.commname = piperComittee.commname
  AND piperComittee.profname = 'Piper'
WHERE piperComittee.profname IS NULL
```

Description:

1. Get all `committee`
2. Join it with this `committee` where is 'Piper'
3. Select only records, where joined `committee` is empty, so there not exists 'Piper'
4. Show only distinct records